# Brace initialization of numeric types. Are they 0-initialized?

Tags: c++

I would like to be sure that the following

```
int i{};
double x{};
```

initialize all the variables to 0. My compiler seems to do that in all modes, but I need to be sure that it is clearly stated by the standard.

Any reference to the C++11 standard is welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is stated by the standard (all quotes from N3337).

`T x{};` is *list-initialization*.

> `[dcl.init.list]/1:` List-initialization is initialization of an object or reference from a braced-init-list.Such an initializer is
>   called an initializer list, and the comma-separated initializer-clauses of the list are called the elements of the
>   initializer list. An initializer list may be empty. [...]

The applicable definition for list-initialization:

> `[dcl.init.list]/3:` List-initialization of an object or reference of type T is defined as follows:
>
> - [lots of non-applicable rules]
> - Otherwise, if the initializer list has no elements, the object is value-initialized.

So that form for built-in types is *value-initialization*:

> `[dcl.init]/7:` To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> - [non-applicable rules]
> - otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

So now we're looking for *zero-initialization* (yes, C++ has a *lot* of types of initialization):

> `[dcl.init]/5:` To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> - if `T` is a scalar type (3.9), the object is set to the value 0 (zero), taken as an integral constant expression, converted to `T;`
> - [...]

Yay, since arithmetic types are scalar types (`[basic.types]/9` if you don't trust me), these forms both initialize their objects with `0`.

Comment: It is always hard to compete (which hours are you sleeping ? ;) ... Thanks for the great demonstration of how to use the Standard !

Answer (score 7):

Yes, this is guaranteed by the standard: this is actually performing [`value-initialization`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

In particular, see the point 4) on the page: it states that it has to be `value-initialization`:

> Value initialization is performed in these situations:
>   ...
>   4) when a named variable (automatic, static, or thread-local) is declared with the initializer consisting of a pair of braces.

And on the same page, you see that the effect of `value-initialization` for built-in types is to initialize them with 0 (square braces are mine):

> The effects of value initialization are:
>   ...
>   4) Otherwise [if non-class, non-array type], the object is zero-initialized.

Answer (score 2):

The `int i{};` form is called [value initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization).

Abridged:

> The effects of value initialization are:
>   [...]
>   4) Otherwise [if T is not a class or array type], the object is zero-initialized.

Comment: Thanks. I have found something in 8.5 Initializers which seem to be a bit different from your quotation. Where does your quotation come from?

Comment: From the cppreference page I linked. Looking at N4140 a very similar section appears in [8.5 *initializers*] / 8 : `To value-initialize an object of type T means: [...]`