# assignment to type and empty braces. clarification on syntax

Tags: c++, syntax, constructor

I just came across some code and I believe I have never seen the syntax shown below.

```
struct A {
  int m_int;
  A (int a = int {}) : m_int(a) {}
};
```

So its clear that the constructor accepts an integer, by value, i.e. `int a` followed by assignment operator and type `int`, and empty braces & right parenthesis close. I am not able to decipher the latter part (`int {}`). What is meant by `int a = int {}`?. Please guide me to find out more about it. How do I address it?

Thank you,
Gaurav

Comment: There is no assignment operator in the example.

Comment: Apologies but I am referring to 'int a = int {}' part of the constructor syntax.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35910619/default-argument-using-curly-braces-initializer

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33913572/brace-initialization-of-numeric-types-are-they-0-initialized

Comment: a temporary is value initialized here 0 and that value is copied to the parameter.

Comment: The second `int` in `int a = int {}` is redundant. `int a = {}` does the same thing.

Comment: Thanks @Maestro. what benefit to we achieve by doing so. does this help us in any special way ?

Comment: The new standard provides curly-braces initialization; one of the benefits is to prevent the narrowing conversion due to implicit conversions.

Comment: I am going to read more about the 'implicit conversions'. I was not aware of it. Need to study more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In you constructor you are defining a constructor that takes an integer and the default constructor. Remember that a constructor that provides default arguments for all of its parameters defines also the default constructor.

- You can write it this way:

  A (int a = 0); // a is a default parameter.

In your example:

```
A (int a = int {});//
```

The parameter `a` is a default parameter initialized (not assigned) from a temporary integer which is value-initialized so because it is integer then it is value-initialized to 0 and then is used to initialize the parameter a. (a is a copy of it). Compiler optimize the code to remove the copy in many scenarios.

```
A (int a = int {5.6});// error
A (int a = int(5.6));// truncated to 5
```

Comment: Yes. Now I understand it better. this was very helpful. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 1):

> followed by assignment operator

No. This is not an assignment operation. This is syntax for default argument. It means that you can invoke the constructor without passing the argument explicitly, in which case `int {}` will be passed instead. The subexpression is syntax for value initialisation of a temporary object.

Comment: Yes. Rightly pointed out. It is not an assignment as I wrote it.